# request id is null in Handle the Incoming Notification in facebook android sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I'm trying to handle incoming Notification in facebook.

ref : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/app-link-requests/

Code :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private String requestId;
private TextView username;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment.onCreate()");
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment.onCreateView()");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login,container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textusename);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment.onActivityCreated()");

    // Check for an incoming notification. Save the info
    // Parse any incoming notifications and save

    Uri intentUri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
    if (intentUri != null) {
        String requestIdParam = intentUri.getQueryParameter("request_ids");
        if (requestIdParam != null) {
            String array[] = requestIdParam.split(",");
            requestId = array[0];
        }
    }


}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    // Check if the user is authenticated and
    // an incoming notification needs handling 
    Log.d(TAG,"MainFragment.onSessionStateChange()");

    Log.d(TAG, "Request id : "+requestId);

    if (state.isOpened() && requestId != null) {
        Log.d("request id", requestId);

        getRequestData(requestId);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Incoming request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        requestId = null;
    }

    if (state.isOpened())
    {
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);


        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), new GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    username.setText(user.getName());
                }                   
            }
        });

    }



}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void getRequestData(String requestid)
{
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), requestid, null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            // Process the returned response
            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            // Default message
            String message = "Incoming request";

            if( graphObject != null )
            {
                // Check if there is extra data
                if ( graphObject.getProperty("data") != null )
                {
                    try {

                        // Get the data, parse info to get the key/value info

                        JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(graphObject.getProperty("data").toString());

                        // Get the value for the key - badge_of_awesomeness
                        String badge = dataObject.getString("badge_of_awesomeness");

                        // Get the value for the key - social_karma
                        String karma = dataObject.getString("social_karma");

                        // Get the sender's name
                        JSONObject fromObject =(JSONObject) graphObject.getProperty("from");

                        String sender = fromObject.getString("name");
                        String title = sender+" sent you a gift";

                        // Create the text for the alert based on the sender
                        // and the data
                        message = title + "\n\n" + "Badge: " + badge + " Karma: " + karma;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "Request : "+request.toString());

    // Execute the request asynchronously.
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

}
}
```

Logcat

```
03-02 17:40:20.443: D/MainFragment(947): MainFragment.onCreate()
03-02 17:40:20.463: D/MainFragment(947): MainFragment.onCreateView()
03-02 17:40:20.753: D/MainFragment(947): MainFragment.onActivityCreated()
03-02 17:40:28.623: D/MainFragment(947): MainFragment.onSessionStateChange()
03-02 17:40:28.623: D/MainFragment(947): Request id : null
03-02 17:40:30.673: D/MainFragment(947): MainFragment.onSessionStateChange()
03-02 17:40:30.673: D/MainFragment(947): Request id : null
03-02 17:40:30.823: D/MainFragment(947): MainFragment.onSessionStateChange()
03-02 17:40:30.833: D/MainFragment(947): Request id : null
```

Now my problem is that when I click on Notification using Facebook android app my app is start but I can not get the request id for that notification.

App Dashboard Configuration
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem I have spent whole day on it. Thanks to Boban

> This is Facebook bug. Just add Mobile Web in App Dashboard and you will get request_ids

[Android app : Handling app request posted on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550361/android-app-handling-app-request-posted-on-facebook/15636105#15636105)

Comment: Hello Nick, I am having same kinda problem and you can check my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324963/unable-to-get-facebook-incoming-requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324963/unable-to-get-facebook-incoming-requests) also.If possible then please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you didn't forget the `requestId` attribute:

```
private String requestId;
```

Could you also check the values of `intentUri`, `requestIdParam` and `array[0]` in the `onActivityCreated` method?

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // <--- in THIS method
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "MainFragment.onActivityCreated()");

    // Check for an incoming notification. Save the info
    Uri intentUri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
    Log.d(TAG, "intentUri: " + intentUri.toString()); // <--- HERE
    if (intentUri != null) {
        String requestIdParam = intentUri.getQueryParameter("request_ids");
        Log.d(TAG, "requestIdParam: " + requestIdParam); // <--- HERE
        if (requestIdParam != null) {
            String array[] = requestIdParam.split(",");
            Log.d(TAG, "requestId: " + array[0]); // <--- HERE
            requestId = array[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Please update your post to show us the whole class.

**Edit:**

> When the user taps on a notification in Facebook for Android, **the
>   class you configured in the App Dashboard settings** will be invoked and
>   the request information will pass into the intent data. The data will
>   have the following information:

```
target_url=[URL]/?request_ids=[COMMA_SEPARATED_REQUESTIDs]
    &ref=notif&fb_source=notification
    &app_request_type=user_to_user
```

However, you don't get the `request_ids` parameter. In my opinion, there is something wrong with the following configuration:
[image: App Dashboard settings]

What did **you** put in these fields? Does it tally with your actual app arborescence?

**Edit 2:**

> **Class Name:** This is the class name of the main activity you want
>   Facebook to launch.

What is there in your `Login.java`?

It should be `com.pricus.expensemanagement.MainActivity`.

Make sure you've correctly followed [this first tutorial about login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/), and particularly this step:

> First, make the activity subclass FragmentActivity instead of
>   Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Comment: No, I'm asking you to print the values of the above-named variables. Post edited with `HERE` statements. Do that and answer with the results of the three `log.d`.

Comment: in logcat I'm getting null

Comment: Read again my last comment and answer the request. Can't believe you added +50 to your post and you don't even bother answering seriously. I want 3 (THREE) values.

Comment: Sorry.I have add the logcat output

Comment: Seriously? This is still not what I want. I know since the beginning that requestId is NULL in `onSessionStateChange`. Your logcat output states what we already know. But tell me, do you read what I write? I'm asking you to add 3 `logs.d` in the `onActivityCreated` method. After three comments, you still didn't understand and we didn't progress at all. (Ok, I'll give you a hint because I'm nice: you only have to copy/paste my `onActivityCreated` method into your code). Then update again the logcat output.

Comment: Logcat : D/MainFragment(487): intentUri: http://apps.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=504782202896276

Comment: Their is no "request_ids" parameter in intentUri= "http://apps.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=504782202896276". so how it can print the value of "requestIdParam" parameter

Comment: Can you check that you indeed received the notification by connecting to your test user on Facebook (not on your app)? We need to know whether you successfully realized the [first task](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/).

Comment: Yes.I received the notification in facebook. when i click on notification my app is start

Comment: Did you configure the "[App Dashboard Configuration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/app-link-requests/#prerequisities)" correctly? Could you show us?

Comment: Yes. I can do anything with my current app Dashboard configuration. like send request,post a story, get user data using fql query etc. and what you want to see in app dashboard configuration

Comment: I've edited my answer. What did you put in the `Package Name`, `Class Name`, `Key Hash`, `Facebook Login` and `Deep Linking` fields?